# working with structs and returning 2d arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm facing some trouble to find the best way to return an struct with an array or pointer to an array.

here is what i want to do:
i have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    double *matrix;
    int cols;
    int rows;
    int nelems;
} ResultMat;
```

and a function that parses a file. I need to call that function and have it return the struct

```
ResultMat read (string file, string tag) {

  ResultMat mat;

  .....
  mat.cols = //some value from the file
  mat.rows = //some value from the file


  double array[rows][cols];
  //now i fill the array

  .......
  mat.matrix = *array;

  return mat;
}
```

within an array is filled with the values and i want to get back that whole struct with the 
array/ pointer to the array stored in mat.matrix.

How to do that and is there maybe a better way? Im quite new to C and more familiar with OO programming, thats why I'm having trouble to find the best solution.

Hope anybody can give me some help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that 
`double array[rows][cols];`
will be a problem, as you create the array on the local function stack.
This will be erased once you leave the function.
You should also be aware of, that Variable-Length arrays are not ANSI-C conform and you should better not use it in my opinion.

You should work with pointers and dynamic memory allocation.
malloc would be the keyword here.

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't get frustrated!! Pointers with multidimensional arrays is one the things in C which can drive you nuts!! I'm speaking out of experience :-)

Comment: what i forgot ... the array itself is not dynamic as rows and cols are fixed numbers. so this means i have to malloc a new array each time the method is called?

Comment: yes indeed its a little bit confusing, especially because im used to just returning  objects. parsing the file was a pain but now that works with little code C .... i hope to understand the rest of it as well ;)

Comment: If the array dimensions are fixed, you should make preprocessor defines for them and not use variables

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I can think of, is to put all the output arguments as input pointers so that your prototype function would look like this:

```
void read (string file, string tag, double *matrix, int *cols, int *rows, int *nelms);
```

or you can keep the structure and go for something like this:

```
void read (string file, string tag, ResultMat *myStructure);
```

IMO, there is no "better way", these are all just different options, yours is another option, which I found myself using very often.